# angular how to access formgroup property for ngClass

Tags: angular, formgroups

i am using formGroup like below:

```
  this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        purchaser: ['buyer', Validators.required],
      });
```

In typescript i now use

```
this.firstFormGroup.get('purchaser')
```

I need to switch style class using ngClass but I am not sure how do i access this property in the HTML. Typically i use the form for a direct class property as below.

```
[ngClass]="purchaser === 'seller' ? 'card-selected' : ''"
```

i can use a class function like getPurchaser() to get value but is there a shorter way like

this.firstFormGroup. ???? to avoid writing class functions to access the value?

Comment: Try this in html : `[ngClass]="firstFormGroup.purchaser === 'seller' ? 'card-selected' : '' " `

Comment: that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the getter property in component.ts file will solve the problem

In component.ts

```
get purchaser() {
  return this.firstFormGroup.get('purchaser').value;
}
```

and in html, you can access the purchaser

```
[ngClass]="purchaser === 'seller' ? 'card-selected' : ''"
```

Another way is to directly use

```
[ngClass]="firstFormGroup.get('purchaser').value === 'seller' ? 'card-selected' : ''"
```

Comment: direct way is the one i was looking for